# How to write a unit test for the code which is having a autofield value as primary key in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am new to testing please help and thanks in advance

BackupRequestmodel

```
class BackupRequest(models.Model):
    request_no = models.ForeignKey(AllRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requirement = models.CharField(max_length=49)
    backup_type = models.CharField(max_length=49)
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
             def __str__(self):
        return self.request_no.__str__()
```

How to write a unit test for this model the dependent models are given below

AllRequestModel

```
class AllRequest(models.Model):
    form_type = models.ForeignKey(RequestType, related_name='requests', default=None, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_no = models.AutoField(max_length=50, default=None, primary_key=True, )
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    requested_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='')
    requested_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.request_no)
```

RequestTypeModel

```
class RequestType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code-writing platform, we can help with specific problems, not "how to [something]"

Comment: I'm not convinced that there is much added value in testing a Django feature itself. Usually one should expect that Django works properly (since it is tested itself). Usually one implements tests to test the business logic, views, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was making a mistake. I was trying to pass the temporary instance of `all_request()` instead of saving it first using `all_request.save()`.

Comment: @pissall please be more careful when you review. A post containing "thank you" alone isn't enough to qualify it as a "thank you" answer. Lots of people use "thank you" as a salutation. This is an answer. There's also no other answers, and no comments suggesting it.